# Mysql : how to re-encode in UTF8?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I am working on an exiting database.
All fields seems to be UTF8

[image]

Problem is : when I edit some fields in phpmyadmin: I got these chars

> En athlÃ©tisme

and selecting ISO-8859-1 works fine

```
mysql_select_db('myDB');
mysql_set_charset('ISO-8859-1', $con1);
```

whereas

```
mysql_select_db('myDB');
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $con1);
```

gives

> En athlÃ©tisme

Question : How can I make it clean and re-encode it all in UTF8 ?

Comment: And the letter you wanted to be printed instead of `Ã©` was `é`? In utf8 `é` is encoded as the two byte sequence `C3 A9`. Now if something along the way interpreted that sequence as single-byte latin1 characters it would become `Ã©` (also encoded as `C3 A9` but latin1). When you look into the table contents again via phpmyadmin, do you see `Ã©` or `é`?

Comment: well i have never had such a problem with phpmyadnin, its pages are all using utf8

Comment: Is it possible that an application accessing the database is incorrectly handling character encoding (other than PHPMyAdmin)?

Comment: Could also be just the output of _your_ script. If it "signals" (e.g. via "Content-type=...;charset=iso-8859-1")  the client/browser that the contents is latin1 encoded but actually sends utf8 characters, the client/Browser will show `Ã©` instead of `é`.

Comment: The only safe way to look at the bytes in a table is via `SELECT col, HEX(col) ...`.  When you look at it through phpmyadmin (or any other client), the connection may be doing conversions.  You have Mojibake because not everything is utf8.

Comment: Do not use `mysql_*` interface; change to `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.